# How to hide KeyBoard in ios9 (Ipad)

Tags: ios, swift, uikeyboard

I edit text in  textField，and add UIKeyboardWillHideNotification to notification centre.

Click the keyboard icon which is in the bottom-right corner in the keyboard to  hide the keyboard。

But I find the Shortcuts Bar(paste/undo ) still exist,and i do not get the notification(UIKeyboardWillHideNotification).
It works ok on ios8.
[image]

-->Click the keyboard icon

[image]]

When click the keyboard icon in the keyboard, it will trigger the  UIKeyboardWillHideNotification in ios8, then i resignFirstResponder for textField and make the textfield lost cursor.But it can not trigger the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification in ios9. So i think it causes by the keyboard is not hidden completely(the tools bar) when click the keyboard icon in ios9. i want to know how to hide the keyboard completely in ios9 when click the keyboard icon. or any other solution to resign the first response for the textfield when click the keyboard icon.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide your platform details: e.g. iPad or iPhone and a screenshot of how the toolbar is still there.

Comment: Is there still an entry cursor in the UITextField? Also how do you "add" a UIKeyboardWillHideNotification? Do you mean you listen for it? or you actually post it?

Comment: NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "dismissKeyBoard:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil);

Comment: That is most unusual, especially not getting the notification. Do you get a notification that it will resign first responder? (your textfield). Infact what I am wondering is does it resign first responder? (which would mean loses the cursor)

Comment: Yes,there is still entry cursor in the uitextField ,because                     textField.resignFirstResponder(); is called  in the  'dismissKeyBoard'

Comment: What does resignFirstResponder do, if you call it? I am curious if it can have the desired effect at all. (does it remove everything?_

Comment: When click the keyboard icon in the keyboard, it will trigger the  UIKeyboardWillHideNotification in ios8, then i resignFirstResponder for textField and make the textfield lost cursor.But it can not trigger the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification in ios9

Comment: For example if you were to hide the keybaord from `username` it loos something like this  `self.username.resignFirstResponder()`

Comment: Try calling myInputField.resignFirstResponder() yourself, like after a delay or button press - this will test if it can function correctly.

Comment: yes,I know it should call resignFirstResponder(),but i can not catch the event that  clicking the keyboard icon(the bottom- right in the keyboard)

Comment: Call it yourself. Use a 2 second delay after editing begins or the keyboard shows. Then, in theory the keyboard should disappear, if it disappears wit the toolbar then you know something is wrong with what you are doing, if not, perhaps it is a system thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"it is showing only in simulator if you try on device it will hide shortcuts also hide on device." – johny kumar

Answer (score 0):

Try this library it will manage automaticall keyboard hide and show.

Paste this line in **didFnishLaunchingWithOption** method in **AppDelegate**

```
IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true
```

[KeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager)

Comment: The problem is that when a perfectly routine user-triggered keyboard close fails to remove its tool-bar. I'm not sure this would solve it as he doesn't need to invoke close programmatically.

Comment: Are you testing it on simulator?